# AWS ElasticSearch PreBuiltTransportClient java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I've created a Java project in Eclipse IDE and in a class have this code. I have included all the jar file dependencies.

```
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY,Arrays.asList(
                Netty3Plugin.class,
                Netty4Plugin.class,
                ReindexPlugin.class,
                PercolatorPlugin.class,
                MustachePlugin.class))
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress
                .getByName("https://search-my-test-domain-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"), 9300));
```

But when I run the code this error comes,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.addPlugins(Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/util/Collection;)Ljava/util/Collection;
at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:125)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:111)
at ESConnManager.retrieveDataFromES(ESConnManager.java:572)
at ESConnManager.main(ESConnManager.java:166)
```

I'm using elasticsearch v5.3.2 and using the java api v5.3. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify those five plugins as they are already loaded by default by the `PreBuiltTransportClient` constructor as can be seen [in the source code of `PreBuiltTransportClient`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/5.3/client/transport/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/transport/client/PreBuiltTransportClient.java#L84-L91)

So use this instead:

```
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
    .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress
            .getByName("https://search-my-test-domain-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"), 9300));
```

However, since you're trying to hit an AWS managed ES cluster, just know that the transport client is not supported, you can only access AWS ES instances via HTTP and not via TCP. The next error you'll get is that the node is not available.

Comment: I still get the NoSuchMethod error, even if I don't specify the plugins. Any other idea?

Comment: Are you certain that you don't have another elasticsearch JAR dependency that is being included by mistake?

Comment: I have added elasticsearch-5.3.2.jar,rest-5.3.2.jar,transport-5.3.2.jar from elasticsearch.

    RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(
           new HttpHost("search-my-test-domain-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com", 80, "http"))) .build();

This works fine. But for the TransportClient i keep getting the same error.

Comment: As I mentioned in my last paragraph, you won't be able to use the Transport client anyway since AWS ES won't allow you to connect on TCP ports. Stick with the RestClient